# Want to make Scrolling Effect on image with css or jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

My requirement is to show a bit of hero image on load and then as I scroll complete image should unfold.

reference website : https://karpov.paris/ (similar hero image effect)

I tried exploring several links, all the links are explaining about zoom-out effect.

Can you please help me to meet my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fkarpov.paris%2f

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a simple demo. I hope it can help you.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $(".zoom img").css({
  transform: 'translate3d(-50%, -'+(scroll/100)+'%, 0) scale('+(100 + scroll/5)/100+')',
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
 position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 40px;
}
.zoom{
  height: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 55%;
}
.zoom img{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0%;
 left: 50%;
 max-width: 150%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoom">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200" alt="img"/>
</div>

<div class="content">
  Put some content here.
</div>
```